# Searching BST element function in C

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree

i think this must be simple problem, but i don't know what's wrong..

gdb says

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555543e in searchNode (root=0x0, X=1) at problem1.c:40
40      while(cursor->value != X || cursor != NULL)
```

insertion and searching function

```
typedef struct TreeNode
{
    int value;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
    struct TreeNode *parent;
}   tree;

tree *insert(tree *root, int X)
{
    tree *cursor = root;
    tree *parent;

    while(cursor != NULL)
    {
        parent = cursor;
        if(X >= cursor->value)
            cursor = cursor->right;
        else
            cursor = cursor->left;
    }
    cursor = (tree *)malloc(sizeof(tree));
    cursor->value = X;
    cursor->left = cursor->right = NULL;
    cursor->parent = parent;
        return cursor;  
}

tree *searchNode(tree *root, int X)
{
    tree *cursor = root;

    while(cursor->value != X || cursor != NULL)
    {
        if(X >= cursor->value)
            cursor = cursor->right;
        else
            cursor = cursor->left;
    }

    if(cursor == NULL)
        return NULL;

    else if(cursor->value == X)
        return cursor;
}
```

main function

```
int main()
{
    tree *root = (tree *)malloc(sizeof(tree));
    root = NULL;

    insert(root, 10);
    insert(root ,20);
    insert(root, 5);
    insert(root, 1);
    insert(root, 15);
    insert(root, 20);
    insert(root, 30);
    insert(root, 100);
    insert(root, 40);
    insert(root, 50);

    node = searchNode(root, 1);
}
```

As far as i know, segmentation error mostly comes out when i reference NULL pointer, but i don't think search function is wrong.
I think i made mistakes in insertion function or initializing tree root, but i don't know what's wrong..

Comment: GDB kindly tells you at which line there is a problem. Nothing prevents you from inspecting the contents of your variables in GDB. Follow some GDb tutorial, there must be tons of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity, I looked into the code.

> i don't think searching function is wrong

I don't agree!

Look at this line of code:

```
while(cursor->value != X || cursor != NULL)
```

What happens if `cursor` is `NULL`? `cursor->value` is accessed which is [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) (because accessing `NULL` is not allowed). This is worth a `Segmentation fault`.

Better would be:

```
while (cursor != NULL && cursor->value != X)
```

or shorter:

```
while (cursor && cursor->value != X)
```

Recalling OP's snippet from gdb

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555543e in searchNode (root=0x0, X=1) at problem1.c:40
40      while(cursor->value != X || cursor != NULL)
```

(which I didn't realize on the first glance) this sounds very reasonable to me.

According to (`root = 0x0`), `searchNode()` seems to be called for an empty tree (`root` is `NULL`). Hence, `tree *cursor = root;` initializes `cursor` with a `NULL` pointer (and the rest above).

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. i must be confused concept of OR and AND..

Comment: @신현섭 Yeah. And the order of arguments of `&&` is important as well. `&&` and `||` are [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). I.e. if first argument of `&&` evaluates to false second is not evaluated. That's why it works in the order I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your `insert` function, is that it has no means of updating the value of `root`. You return the new leaf node, but that isn't of much use to you in tracking what `root` might be.

To be able to change `root` you have to pass in a pointer to it, like for example:

```
insert(&root, 10);
```

And then you could change your function like this. It traverses down the tree, passing in a pointer to the left or right branch of the current node until it finds that the node doesn't exist yet and then it creates it.

```
tree *insert(tree **root, int X)
{
    if(*root == NULL)
    {
        *root = (tree *)malloc(sizeof(tree));
        (*root)->value = X;
        (*root)->left = (*root)->right = (*root)->parent = NULL;
        return(*root);
    }
    else
    {
        tree *ret;
        if(X >= (*root)->value)
        {
            ret=insert(&(*root)->right, X);
            (*root)->right->parent=*root;
        }
        else
        {
            ret=insert(&(*root)->left, X);
            (*root)->left->parent=*root;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

So the first time you call it, it'll populate `root` for you. The second time, it will pass in the pointer to `root->right` which will become the new `root` in your `insert` function and since that is `NULL`, it'll be created. And then for completeness sake it updates the `parent` linkage.